# Two array in one foreach Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have two table the first called **codes**, and second is **company**.

**Codes** table structure:

 id| title | desc | company | order

**Company** table structure:

 id| name

Here is code from my controller

```
 $codes= DB::table('codes')->orderBy('company', 'ASC')->get();
 $company = Company::all();
 return view('codes.index',compact('codes', 'company'));
```

And here is codes from my view.

```
 @foreach($codes as $code)
   <tr>
    <td>{{$code->title}}</td>
    <td>{{$code->code}}</td>
    <td>{{$company->name}}</td>  
    <td>{{$code->order}}</td>
   </tr>
  @endforeach
```

I can not get name of company. How is possible? Thanks for all

Comment: How do you know which company belongs to which code? Currently you are trying to displaying a random company for a code, what is the point of this?

Comment: You did not defin `$codes` on your controller, how can you get `$codes` on blade ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$services = Services::orderBy('company', 'ASC')->with('company')->get();
return view('services.index',compact('services'));
```

view

```
@foreach($codes as $code)
   <tr>
    <td>{{$code->title}}</td>
    <td>{{$code->code}}</td>
    <td>{{$code->company->name}}</td>  
    <td>{{$code->order}}</td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

I did not know the names exactly because I wrote them because of that approximation.
If the company is defined as id, you can get company information using.
You just have to define this model in the service model.

```
 public function company()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo(Companies::class);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your view code with this

```
 @foreach($codes as $key => $code)
   <tr>
    <td>{{$code->title}}</td>
    <td>{{$code->code}}</td>
    <td>{{$company[$key]->name}}</td>  
    <td>{{$code->order}}</td>
   </tr>
  @endforeach
```

And it'll work